# Why is WiFi P2P group owner is constant 192.168.49.1?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifip2p

I'm using Android's API for Wi-Fi p2p.

As I see in Android's source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/84befe36af491f26ae46243017a1aca4dd5b24d5/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pServiceImpl.java):

```
private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "192.168.49.1";
```

Do you have any idea why is it constant?
I want to change it to a different address.
Is it possible?

Comment: Link to source please?

Comment: That it is a fixed ip comes in quit handy. Why do you wanna change it?

Comment: I want to add another interface, and not have ip conflict.

Comment: In which scenario is there an ip conflict? Copy the file to your project and change the ip.

Comment: Copying the file doesn't work since it includes imports of packages which are not available to normal api user.

Comment: The group owner acts like an AP to the P2P network hence it has assigned default gateway-like address. As the P2P network is managed by GO there is no way for IP conflict to occur (GO assigns IPs dynamically).